# service fabric asp .net core IoC error : cannot be dynamically proxied

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, autofac, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to put some IoC in my api and keep getting this error :

> The type Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade.Facade cannot be dynamically proxied. Service types must not be sealed and need to be visible to the DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 assembly. This can be achieved by making the type public or adding the InternalsVisibleToAttribute to the assembly containing the type. e.g. [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]

```
program.cs:
//[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]
namespace Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade
{
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the entry point of the service host process.
    /// </summary>
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new GlobalAutofacModule());
            builder.RegisterServiceFabricSupport();
            builder.RegisterStatelessService<Facade>("Inovatic.SF.Windows.FacadeType");

            using (builder.Build())
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(Facade).Name);
                Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class GlobalAutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ConfigSettings>();
        builder.RegisterType<PaymentRepository>().As<IPaymentRepository>();
    }
}
```

}

I've tried to put this (but not sure where it should go) :

> [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]

and also tried to mark the Program class as public but that doesn't seem to work

EDIT:

```
namespace Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade
{
internal sealed class Facade : StatelessService
{
    public Facade(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { 
        var telemetryConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
        telemetryConfig.InstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApplicationInsightsKey");
        FabricTelemetryInitializerExtension.SetServiceCallContext(context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional override to create listeners (like tcp, http) for this service instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The collection of listeners.</returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        var endpoints = Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoints()
            .Where(endpoint => endpoint.Protocol == EndpointProtocol.Http 
            || endpoint.Protocol == EndpointProtocol.Https);

        return endpoints.Select(endpoint => new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, endpoint.Name, (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                return new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        if (endpoint.Protocol == EndpointProtocol.Http)
                            options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, endpoint.Port);
                        else if (endpoint.Protocol == EndpointProtocol.Https)
                            options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, endpoint.Port,
                                listenOptions => listenOptions.UseHttps(Certificates.GetCertificateFromLocalStore(
                                        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClusterCertifThumbprint"))));
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices(
                        services =>
                        {
                            services
                                .AddSingleton(new ConfigSettings())
                                .AddSingleton(serviceContext)
                                .AddSingleton(new HttpClient())
                                .AddSingleton(new FabricClient());
                        })
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                    .UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"))
                    .UseUrls(url)
                    .UseApplicationInsights()
                    .Build();
            }), endpoint.Name));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to post the code of your service. Not of `program.cs`

Comment: I'm not sure what other part would help, anything specific you need to see?

Comment: Of `Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade.Facade`

Comment: that's the first strange thing of the error message, I have Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade but not Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade.Facade

Comment: So let me get this straight: you do not have a class `Facade` in namespace `namespace Inovatic.SF.Windows.Facade`?  Can you post the full code (including namespaces) of the `Facade`  you *do* have?

Comment: I do sorry, misunderstanding, main post has been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the `Facade` class public and remove the `sealed` keyword (Because the autofac creates a proxy class that inherits from your class. If it is sealed that is prohibited).

So change

```
internal sealed class Facade : StatelessService
```

to

```
public class Facade : StatelessService
```

Then you do not need this anymore

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]
```

Comment: won't that introduce any security concern?

Comment: Why? making a type public only allows other assemblies that take a dependency on this assembly to use this class. But that is under your control. What kind of security concern are we talking about? It won't magically make this service public from the internet if that is what you may think.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, switching to public sealed class Facade or public class Facade , makes the service unhealthy apparently ...

Comment: Nevermind it works, but the "sealed" still needs to be removed

Comment: yeah that is because the autofac creates a proxy class that inherits from your class. If it is sealed that is prohibited. I'll update my answer accordingly